# How to move data from Cassandra to Hbase

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hbase, sqoop, flume

Currently we have a requirement to move the data to Cassandra NOSQL database and in future we can move to Hbase from cassandra.

It will be great if some one suggest the best approach for this activities.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Spark, it has good connectivity with both Databases.